# XSLT: can't select correct ancestor by name

Tags: xml, xslt

I am getting confusing behavior when trying to select an ancestor node in an XML file. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document version="2">
  <interlinear-text>
    <paragraphs>
      <paragraph>
        <phrases>
          <phrase>
            <item type="segnum" lang="en">1.1</item>
            <words>
              <word>
                <morphemes>
                  <morph type="stem">
                    <item type="cf" lang="tmy-Latn">yau</item>
                    <item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">yau</item>
                    <item type="gls" lang="en">1S</item>
                  </morph>
                </morphemes>
              </word>
              <word>
                <morphemes>
                  <morph type="stem">
                    <item type="cf" lang="tmy-Latn">ma</item>
                    <item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">ma</item>
                    <item type="gls" lang="en">and</item>
                  </morph>
                </morphemes>
              </word>
              ...
```

So, in the XSLT I am in a template matching the morph/item nodes, and I try using `ancestor::*[word]` and instead it returns the `<words>` element. Even if I say `ancestor::*[word][1]`. Why is it selecting an element that doesn't even match what I asked for?! How do I get it to select the word element by name from the item element using the ancestor function?

Comment: what are the nodes you want to access to?

Comment: Huh? I said I want to select the <word> nodes. The ancestor of any given <item> node being evaluated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath to find all the `<word>` nodes that do respect the constraint item[1] text equals `ma`, you can adapt the extraction condition as you want.

**XPATH:**

```
//morphemes/morph/item[1][text()='ma']/ancestor::word
```

**DEMO:**

```
(xmllint --xpath "//morphemes/morph/item[1][text()='ma']/ancestor::word" test_ancestors.xml; echo) | xmllint --format -
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<word>
  <morphemes>
    <morph type="stem">
      <item type="cf" lang="tmy-Latn">ma</item>
      <item type="txt" lang="tmy-Latn">ma</item>
      <item type="gls" lang="en">and</item>
    </morph>
  </morphemes>
</word>
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: That is not exactly what I was looking for, but your answer did clue me in to the fact that I was supposed to just say `ancestor::word`, not `ancestor::*[word]`. I just had no clue how XPATH's crazy syntax works. So you should simplify your answer.

Comment: Using any language by trial and error without understanding how its syntax works seems very likely to lead to (a) your code not working, and (b) your coming to the conclusion that the syntax is crazy. In fact it is highly logical. `ancestor::*` selects all ancestors, a predicate `[...]` filters that to select only certain ancestors, the predicate `[word]` is short for `[child::word]` which selects anything that has a child called `word`. Your problem is that you were guessing.